# Import a subfolder with all sub-subfolders and their his files, but without specifying individual files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, python-import

I have a problem with imports of subfolder with all sub-subfolder and all their files. I would like to import all `THIS FOLDER4` (including its subfolders and related subfolder files) into file `here.py`, without manually specifying folder6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, and without specifying the py files.

I have so many subfolders and so many .py files (much more than the example in the question), so I wouldn't want to manually specify them with import. I would like folder `THIS FOLDER4` to automatically take all its contents (all subfolders and all files) and import it.

So after importing the subfolders, I DON'T want to write for example import file.py, but I want all of them to be automatically taken from each subfolder. The same also for the subfolders, I DON'T want to specify them all subfolders manually, but take them automatically from THIS FOLDER 4.

In conclusion, what I would like is to import all the contents of THIS FOLDER 4, therefore: Folder5 and its files, Folder6 and its files, Folder7 and its files, Folder8 and its files, and so also for the other folders up to Folder13 and the his files. I would like NOT to specify the above folders and their files, but I would like something that makes me write only THIS FOLDER4 (and its path if needed) and then all its contents are automatically taken without specifying anything. Thank you!

```
Project_Main_Folder
└── folder1
    └── folder2
        └── folder3
            └── THIS FOLDER4
                └── __init__.py
                └── FOLDER5
                    └── folder6
                         ├── file1.py
                         ├── file2.py
                         └── __init__.py               
                    └── folder7
                         ├── file3.py
                         ├── file4.py
                         └── __init__.py 
                └── FOLDER8
                    └── folder9
                         ├── file5.py
                         ├── file6.py
                         └── __init__.py               
                    └── folder10
                         ├── file7.py
                         ├── file8.py
                         └── __init__.py    
                └── FOLDER11
                    └── folder12
                         ├── file9.py
                         ├── file10.py
                         └── __init__.py             
                    └── folder13
                         ├── file11.py
                         ├── file12.py
                         └── __init__.py    
            └── folderrr
                 └── here.py (I need to import the folder THIS FOLDER4 here)
```

I tried to write this, but it doesn't work:

```
import Project_Main_Folder.folder1.folder2.folder3.THIS FOLDER4

#or

from Project_Main_Folder.folder1.folder2.folder3.THIS FOLDER4 import *

#or

import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/home/Desktop/Project_Main_Folder/folder1/folder2/folder3/THIS FOLDER4/')
```

What is the simplest and shortest code solution to get what I want?

Can you show me a code example, related to my folders? Thank you all!

Comment: I think there might be a bit of a misunderstanding of how the python import system works. Take a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) to get some pointers.